# SoilGrids physical soil - Sand.tif impossible to open

Tags: soilgrids

I have been downloading physical soil data using SoilGrids python package for sand, silt, cfvo, bdod and clay.

I used the exact same code for all 5 features, but I am facing an issue with sand.

When I run the following code, all data are downloaded as .tif files

```
from soilgrids import SoilGrids

soil_grids = SoilGrids()

soil_types = ["silt", "cfvo", "bdod", "clay", "sand"]

output_directory = "MY_PATH_TO_DIR"

for soil in soil_types:
    output_file = output_directory / f'{soil}.tif'

    soil_grids.get_coverage_data(
        service_id=s, coverage_id=f'{s}_60-100cm_mean',
        west=-5.14, south=42.25, east=8.23, north=51.09,
        height=3936, width=5953,
        crs='urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326',
        output=output_file)
```

But then, I have an issue opening sand.tif file.
When I execute the following code for silt, bdod, clay or cfvo, there is no issue and data loads when `src.read(1)` is executed.

```
with rasterio.open(MY_PATH_TO_/silt.tif") as src:
    width = src.width
    height = src.height
    transform = src.transform
    src.read(1)
```

When I replace silt.tif by sand.tif, i have the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CPLE_AppDefinedError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
File rasterio/_io.pyx:975, in rasterio._io.DatasetReaderBase._read()

File rasterio/_io.pyx:213, in rasterio._io.io_multi_band()

File rasterio/_err.pyx:195, in rasterio._err.exc_wrap_int()

CPLE_AppDefinedError: PATH/sand.tif, band 1: IReadBlock failed at X offset 1, Y offset 13: TIFFReadEncodedTile() failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

RasterioIOError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
PATH/soilgrids.ipynb Cell 6 line 5
      3 height = src.height
      4 transform = src.transform
----> 5 src.read(1)

File rasterio/_io.pyx:651, in rasterio._io.DatasetReaderBase.read()

File rasterio/_io.pyx:978, in rasterio._io.DatasetReaderBase._read()

RasterioIOError: Read or write failed. MY_PATH_TO/sand.tif, band 1: IReadBlock failed at X offset 1, Y offset 13: TIFFReadEncodedTile() failed.
```

Do you think it is a problem related to the file itself? If so, do you know any other way to download soilgrids sand data?

Comment: Are you sure the file is intact?

Comment: Very hard to answer without test data. There has been some issues in certain GDAL versions reading some compressed TIFF files but the error message that you see is usually correct and means that the TIFF file in corrupted or otherwise invalid. If you can't share the data try to open it with different programs and program versions.

Answer (score 0):

Soilgrids data can be downloaded directly from ISRIC data hub https://data.isric.org

You can download the sand layers from:

- OGC web-services (using QGIS for example) from https://maps.isric.org/mapserv?map=/map/sand.map
- Download the aggregated files from https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data_aggregated

More information can be found at https://www.isric.org/explore/soilgrids